# Unix Syslog not working properly

Tags: unix, cygwin, daemon, syslog

I am using UNIX in cygwin (in Windows 7). I have a syslog.conf file consisting of this line initially:

```
*.*                                     /var/log/messages
```

All information is logged to this "messages" file. Now when I changed the path to a new file (logtest):

```
*.*                                     /var/log/logtest
```

I restarted the syslog-ng daemon, but the information is still getting logged to /var/log/messages

What could be the problem?